# Snapping in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cartography, snapping

I want to add more than one layer to snapping in map

```
var layerInfos = [

  {layer:results[0].layer}

];

snappingManager.setLayerInfos(layerInfos);
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn how this site works.  What GIS software are you using here?

Comment: thanks for your advice i am building a gis application using arcgis javascript api

Answer (score 1):

```
var snapToTheseLayers = [

  {layer: layer1},
  {layer: layer2}, ...//add as many layers as you want

];

snappingManager.setLayerInfos(snapToTheseLayers );
```

Comment: Please edit provide context for your answer.

Comment: not sure what context is needed, took what max4ever suggested and applied it to ESRI's 'Measurement Widget' example

[here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/widget_measurement.html) and it worked great,